# If I have a nested readonly array inside an object, how do I copy that object and convert the array to be mutable (so I can insert into akita)?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-akita

If I have the following interface in typescript

```
interface Member {
   readonly id: number;
   readonly name: string;
   readonly email: string;
   groups: <ReadonlyArray>Group
}

interface Group {
   readonly id: number;
   readonly name: string;
   readonly active: boolean;
}
```

Data would look something like this

```
member {
   id: 1,
   name: 'John Doe',
   email: 'junk@junk.com'
   groups: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Group 1', active: true}
      { id: 2, name: 'Group 2', active: false}
      { id: 3, name: 'Group 3', active: false}
   ]
}
```

If I wanted to store this in akita/state and allow it to be mutable (ie maybe a user wants to click a checkbox to say 'Group 2' is now active and I need to update the akita/state), how do I make a copy of the entire object so it is not immutable (before inserting into akita/state)?

Ok, I wanted to edit my question after reading below comments.

I have the following code inserting into my akita store

```
  loadMemberById(memberId: number) {
    const request$ = this.membersDataService.getById(memberId).pipe(
      tap(response => this.membersStore.upsert(response.id, response)),
      tap(response => this.membersStore.upsert(response.id, { groups: { 
         ...response.groups } })),
      tap(response => this.membersStore.setHasCache(true))
    );

    return cacheable(this.membersStore, request$);
  }
```

VS is complaining about `state.member.groups` inside of `arrayUpdate`

```
  update(groupId: number, value: boolean): Observable<void> {
    const observer = this.groupsDataService.update(groupId, value);

    observer.subscribe(() => {
      this.sessionStore.update(state => {
        return {
          member: {
            ...state.member,
            groups: arrayUpdate(state.member.groups, data => data.groupId === 
                groupId, {
                    active: value
            })
          }
        };
      });
    });
```

Thx
jonpfl

Answer (score 1):

From [immerjs](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) - Removes readonly:

> Use with caution as this allows you to edit values that may not be meant to be changed

> Best if used in combination with the spread operator/object.assign

```
type AtomicObject =
    | Function
    | Promise<any>
    | Date
    | RegExp
    | Boolean
    | Number
    | String

type Draft<T> = T extends AtomicObject
    ? T
    : T extends ReadonlyMap<infer K, infer V> // Map extends ReadonlyMap
    ? Map<Draft<K>, Draft<V>>
    : T extends ReadonlySet<infer V> // Set extends ReadonlySet
    ? Set<Draft<V>>
    : T extends WeakReferences
    ? T
    : T extends object
    ? {-readonly [K in keyof T]: Draft<T[K]>}
    : T
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case deconstructing the object will not do, as it will copy it together with its readonly state, what you need to do is that:

```
someReadonlyObject; <-- the original immutable object
copiedObject; <-- new copied mutable object

copiedObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(someReadonlyObject));
```

This will create a completely new object, now copiedObject is mutable.

Although be careful to update the store in the correct way using it's .update() function and not by assigning individual values so the state will be aware of the changes.

Answer (score 0):

use spread operator as copy

```
const oldState =....
const groupToadd = {...somegroup...};
const newState = {
... oldState
groups: oldState.groups.concat(groupToAdd)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mutableGroup = { ...readOnlyGroup }
```

Those three points are the spread or rest operator. This operator allows an object or array to be expanded and return the inner variables like the parameters of a function.
This also can be used to make a copy of an instance without altering their values. so in this case it decouples from the readOnly condition and copies the value.